# IS SharePoint 2007 compatible with SQL 2008 SP3?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, sql-server

IS SharePoint 2007 compatible with SQL 2008 SP3? I didnt find any know issues with this combination and or a support document which says it is compatible.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint 2007 is compatible with SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3.

As your link covered the "Supported Combinations of SharePoint and Reporting Services Components", I'm assuming you are after these features. So, for the Reporting Services, you need to have this additional Add-in installed: 
[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP3 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint Technologies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27595&WT.mc_id=aff-n-in-loc--pd)

Comment: We are upgrading the Windows server from 2008 to 2012, and only SQL Server 2008 SP3 is compatible with it and not SQL Server SP2. Unable to find a related literature for this combination ( SharePoint 2007, SQL Server 2008 SP3, Windows Server 2012). Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @AchieverSP I'd advice to ask only one thing per question, but briefly about that: it depends where you are installing Windows Server 2012. SharePoint 2007 **can't** be installed on Windows Server 2012. SQL Server 2008 SP3 **can** be installed on Windows Server 2012 ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2681562/using-sql-server-in-windows-8-and-later-versions-of-windows-operating-system)). You can use SP 2017 with an SQL Server 2008 SP 3 hosted on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Yes but just want to be sure that any patch version of SP 2007 or does it need SP 2007 SP3 to connect SQL Server 2008 SP3 ?

Comment: @AchieverSP I think Benny Skogberg has already answered that question above. See https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/sharepoint-sql-server-support-matrix#.WT7D_OuLRhE - this suggests SP1 is the minimum.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, It's compatible. Just make sure you use MOSS SharePoint Service Pack 3, and you should be just fine.

Also there's no difference to SharePoint concern whether you use SP2 or SP3 on the SQL Server. In general SHarePoint installations work with one version up and down of the current minimum requirements. As SharePoint 2007 minimum requirements are SQL Server 2005, all versions of SQL Server 2008 (including R2) works properly.

Reference: [MOSS 2007 SP3 with SQL Server 2008 R2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c47ccba1-bf93-4abb-a9fd-a526f3424337/moss-2007-sp3-with-sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-2?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

Comment: Doesn't the reference actually contain SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 related discussion, not SP3?

Comment: @moe True, but there are no difference when it comes to SharePoint 2007 whether or not you use SP2 or SP3. Maybe I was a bit sloppy not explaining that :-/

Comment: That supplements the answer well. It's good to be added!

Comment: If it is not MOSS SharePoint Service Pack 3, will that be any problem? i mean lower patch version of SP 2007 doesnt work with SQL 2008 SP3?

Comment: @AchieverSP Sure. To install SP3, you first need vanilla, SP1 and SP2. So it will work ;)